# Don't load until function finishes loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm pulling album photos from Facebook API and then arranging them in masonry style. I have it set up so that I'll run the API function, then when I click a button it'll run the masonry function, which works fine. Now what I want to do is have the masonry run automatically after all the images are downloaded, like so:

```
function fbAPI() {
  //downloading photos and placing them in a div
  masonryFunction();
}

function masonryFunction(){
  //run the masonry plugin
}
```

The trouble I run into though is masonryFunction runs well before fbAPI has finished doing it's thing, which prevents it from working (all the photos must be loaded up first). Now I can't simply have masonryFunction run when the page is loaded because fbAPI doesn't get launched until after some user input. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Call the fbAPI() function in the callback function for the FB login function.

For example,

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        facebookLoggedIn();
    } else {
        alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
    }
});

function facebookLoggedIn() {
    fbAPI();
}
```

Or, subscribe to FB auth.statusChange event:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
    facebookStatusChange(response);
});

function facebookStatusChange(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        uid = response.authResponse.userID;
        accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        facebookLoggedIn();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
        // but has not authenticated your app
    } else {
        // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
    }
}
```